# converting array to object where array values are the object keys and object values are empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a reactjs web app I have an array like

```
let arr = ["name","message", etc...];
```

I want to convert it to object but to look like

```
let desired = { name:'', message:'' };
```

I tried a few things but none of them worked.

Comment: `I tried few things but none worked ` ? can you show code you have tried so far ?

Comment: *reactjs* shouldn't be tagged here as the problem in consideration has nothing to do with reactjs.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to assign each value in the array the value of an empty string, use `reduce`:

```js
let arr = ["name","message", "etc"];
let desired = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr] = "", acc), {});
console.log(desired);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var arr = ["name","message", "etc"];
var desired = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc[curr] = "";
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(desired);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: No problem @zewo, always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let arr = ["name","message", "etc"];
let desired = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    desired[arr[i]] = "";
}
console.log(desired);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `forEach()`

```js
let arr = ['name', 'type', 'id', 'phone'];
let obj = {};
arr.forEach(i=>{obj[i] = ''});

console.log(obj);
```